# Prove that $\left(\frac{-1}{p}\right)\left(\frac{3}{p}\right)=\left(\frac{p}{3}\right)$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, legendre-symbol

Why does  $\left(\frac{-1}{p}\right)\left(\frac{3}{p}\right)$ equal $\left(\frac{p}{3}\right)$?

Comment: two cases, $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ has one proof, $p \equiv 3 \pmod 4$ has the other, both use quadratic reciprocity.

Answer (score 3):

Use quadratic reciprocity :

$$ \left (\frac{p}{3} \right )=\left (\frac{3}{p} \right ) \cdot (-1)^{\frac{3-1}{2} \cdot \frac{p-1}{2}}$$

But we also know that : $$(-1)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}=\left (\frac{-1}{p} \right )$$ and thus the conclusion follows :

$$\left (\frac{p}{3} \right )=\left (\frac{3}{p} \right ) \cdot \left (\frac{-1}{p} \right )$$ by combining the two relations.